# TypeScript Generics: any interface implementer

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, javascript-objects, typescript-generics

I have a problem with generics in TypeScript.

I have an interface called `Obstacle`:

```js
import Shape from "./Shape";

interface Obstacle<S extends Shape> {
    readonly type: string;
    readonly shape: S;
}

export default Obstacle;
```

`Obstacle` is a wrapper around another interface `Shape`:

```js
interface Shape {
    readonly name: string;
}

export default Shape;
```

I can use these two interfaces, to create a class that implements `Shape`, for example `Rectancle` or `Circle`.

Then, I create another class, for example `RectangleObstacle` or `CircleObstacle` which implements `Obstacle<Rectangle>` or `Obstacle<Circle>`, respectively.

But, my question is, when I use them, in an array of obstacles (it should hold any type of obstacle), like this:

```js
import Obstacle from "./Obstacle";

interface Data {
    obstacles: Obstacle<any>[]; /* What should I put here? In the generic parameters list? */
}

const DATA: Data = {
    obstacles: []
};
```

I have tried putting `Obstacle<Shape>[]` and `Obstacle<any extends Shape>[]`, but it doesn't work.
Also, I should be able to distinguish between different types of obstacles, like so:

```js
function somefunc(): void {
    for(let i: number = 0; i < DATA.obstacles.length; i++) {
        const o: Obstacle = DATA.obstacles[i]; /* what to write here? */
        switch(o.type) {
            case "rectangle":
                /* For example, writting this: */
                o.shape.width;
                /* results in: property width does not exist on type Shape */
                break;
            case "circle":
                /* ... */
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does not work with `Obstacle<Shape>[]`? Works pretty well for me

Comment: Properties of shape are nod narrowed with `Obstacle<Shape>[]`

Comment: For properties of shape to be narrowed you should check `o.shape.name`, what's the point of `Obstacle.type` property?

Comment: @AlekseyL. It consider it equivalent solution. If RectangleObstacle always contains rectangles etc (which seems sensible assumption) you can make discriminated union out of shape, not out of obstacle.

Comment: @Lesiak but why wrapper should duplicate `Shape`'s type at the first place? Creating wrapper class per shape to specify the shape's type doesn't seem to be a good solution..

Comment: @AlekseyL. If there is no data specific to each wrapper, than indeed discriminating on shape is more straightforward. In such case, it makes no sense to keep type in the obstacle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)

```
type AppObstacle = RectangleObstacle | CircleObstacle

interface Data {
    obstacles: AppObstacle[]; 
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoAs4AcUG8BQyRyUEcAJgPYgA2AnsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYBufAF98Y0JFiIUAeQBG3RDQgAeVMggAPSCHKc0mHAD5kBYiTJVaDMHRwduvEIMLFSFavS6H2aIaPwJaHgkZAAlCAQwOGdlDW0IXX0MbDxXAHdgcjB0DhAAV2Y5aH9xcGDpZABhYCgEOK0dPQNU01coCmB8zjzC4qgRMXq4Tn0IqJi%20ZXlFepRgZixlVnB9Gei5lXHo2IgTMzdLTxs7FABeZAByUgndy6FzdysvTh8Obcm4i4PzJlYOa4ARkuABpXOZMtlcsgAKwABjB5mEpXww1G1Vqc3WSnmi2WiTAawUG2UKhqdWU%203BFg81mQthwyAulwQmOU92pT2O3lSHHJcyZbXMRD%20vhZwMRwo65C6PWQACYEdTkYN8AyUABBLBYbECi4fXa6uIAHwxFIgRogZUkIRQABE4NEhcRKMScXKtTq3XMANoAXQEyFVCGo3GQdo1ABUNRwHU7vtTXbNlHL-SIhPgYPkQFFgNQuJRWFmcwAKACUHAAbpQss6iDBKFAS8owMhgL0itBBXDA8BkCpw1GNQA6JMkiCcYfKZw5XsAajnZbrwpDIDDlEFEejo%209KZ9wADyAA9AAqZDpTCtsAb9K8SDIdDQCAAfmQJ6P1PMnEyYAQ6BLlDDuqS4-MK5gICMKAAEQ3DsUwQFBbCfmBwqnsgABijbxCwSwQCC553mA-D0ugwByu%20yEoS6w6vKkw6QrOlFUceZ6kJw%20Q0ISbYgBwWBQJQOBQLY55ZDkyBUBOjCUK2Whka2%20bqi0jIUcxKFyO4ADWDyqcgEGcNBrLmohTFUWhw7mW%20H46cKgG0Tgw7SrKJlqZp2lgaISIiEAA)

Also, to apply suggestion by AlekseyL., if obstacle is only a container for shape with no additional data or logic associated with it, you may change Shape to discriminated union as follows:

```
interface Shape {
    readonly type: string;
    readonly name: string;
}

interface Rectangle extends Shape {
  type: 'rectangle';
  width: number;
}

interface Circle extends Shape {
  type: 'circle';
  radius: number
}

type AppShape = Rectangle | Circle;

interface Data {
    obstacles: Obstacle[]; 
}

const DATA: Data = {
    obstacles: []
};

function somefunc(): void {
    for(let i: number = 0; i < DATA.obstacles.length; i++) {
        const o = DATA.obstacles[i]; 
        const shape = o.shape;
        switch(shape.type) {
            case 'rectangle':
                shape.width;
                break;
            case 'circle':
                shape.radius;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoAs4AcUG8BQyRyUEcAJgPYgA2AnsmHTgFzIDOYUoA5gNyFipCtXrIQcALYQ2nbiH74AvvnyhIsRCgBKEBGDgKaKCAA9IIcuzSYcyAkSatkAclL7DPYy4FEA7sDkYOhsIACukgBG0AIqauDQ8EjIAMLAUAjGyGYWVjbYeIJOMq4I6ZkQPoJQFMBh7KER0VDKqsXIAIJYWBgFyAC8yLoeRigAPqnlxgLxGkkoAPKRnIhZDkJkVLQM7LYlXT17saoI1JwkemBswwajA-ZFzCVul57eADSCEtJsbgCMLk%20-kCwTYAFYAAyfOKnEDnMoZYxsNKIlCDdbERhPX4IiqAwSY77PBAAoGYki1epsABMUIJMLOYAu%20iWKwqbFZBgq9wxHD2bHcYFa%20Fh8KmEE5qxKku56IJuwKbFxxmFqnUiS0yAAInADA9MZRllzjA1kDLjABtAC6fGQwtFTK1HQAKh02Dq9XKDUapabrcoZjAwiB9MBqBxKNIgyGABQASjYADdKIF9cQYJQoDHjEzgI0otB7hDbcBkAAebUujoAOkNbJN1eMCmCJYA1K242nycgHchKPcna7az6KuwLcAbXbu0Rewq7INKNW5xBfNP2AEwAh0DHl9Xip3edOe3B2CgXiMvJUWASj%20SAPQAKmQADFM9lTFIsMZ3sg-NwwGAvCMOgwCmg%20d43rexC7gEQToKuUGYo%20FzsGENBgNYoBsFgUCUDgUBML%20ILoMgVAQNYICUEyZigUy4btL0djgZBiGRMIADWCG3ggJ5nsqV4sVByHViJyDMYh5K7jU5B1OwXESWxZCcYJyAqJiKhKEAA)